# Using an SQL Data Adapter to update and insert rows doesn't update (only inserts)

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I am just playing around with this at the moment, ultimately I want to read a CSV file into memory and then insert the records into an SQL database. Existing records should be updated, records that are missing should be added. Records that don't exist in the new CSV shouldn't be deleted, however.

I've been playing around the example from the MSDN library. I understand that the SqlDataAdapter can perform bulk updates quite quickly.

I created a little mock app with a table called `TempTestTable` that has `TempTestTableId`, `Age`, and `Name` columns. I wrote this (based on the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
using (SqlConnection connection =
   new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=fishsticks;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(
      "SELECT temptesttableid, Age, Name FROM TempTestTable",
      connection);

    dataAdpater.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
       "UPDATE TempTestTable SET Age = @Age, Name = @Name " +
       "WHERE TempTestTableId = @TempTestTableId", connection);

    dataAdpater.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
       "INSERT INTO TempTestTable (Age, Name) " +
       "VALUES (@Age, @Name)", connection);

    SqlParameter parameter = dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
       "@TempTestTableId", SqlDbType.Int);

    dataAdpater.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(
      "@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "Age");

    dataAdpater.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(
      "@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");

    dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
      "@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 10, "Age");

    dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
      "@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");

    parameter.SourceColumn = "TempTestTableId";
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    DataTable tempTestTable = new DataTable();

    tempTestTable.Columns.Add("Age");
    tempTestTable.Columns.Add("Name");
    tempTestTable.Columns.Add("TempTestTableId");

    var row1 = tempTestTable.NewRow();

    row1["Age"] = 10;
    row1["Name"] = "Smith";
    row1["TempTestTableId"] = 1;

    var row2 = tempTestTable.NewRow();

    row2["Age"] = 40;
    row2["Name"] = "Jones";
    row2["TempTestTableId"] = 2;

    tempTestTable.Rows.Add(row1);
    tempTestTable.Rows.Add(row2);

    dataAdpater.Update(tempTestTable);
```

There is already a record in the database with `TempTestTableId = 1`, so the idea was that in theory it would update that record, as well as insert a new record with ID 2. However, when I run the code, it inserts both items.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, the `DataAdapter` will just look at the `DataRow`'s [`RowState` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx). If it's `Added` the `InsertCommand` will be executed, if it's `Modified`  the `UpdateCommand` will be executed. You have to load this row  into the table from the database first.

Comment: Originally the example I ripped from MSDN did that, but I need to load from CSV so how can I read from the database and also from the CSV? Do I have to read the current database table into adatatable then loop through it and manually check each row against my CSV, alter the values or insert new rows, and set the RowState, and then commit it?

Comment: You can fill an empty `DataTable` with a `DataAdapter` and your `SelectCommand` including two parameters. If the table is empty you can add the `DataRow` manually, otherwise you can modify the rows with the updated values (if any) and call `dataAdpater.Update(tempTestTable)`.

Comment: Hmm that sounds quite confusing, do you have an example? I'll give it a go regardless

Comment: Think I've got it, I load my database table into a DataTable, do all the operations (add, update etc.) then call `.Update()`. That seemed to do it, hopefully it'll be speedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `DataAdapter` will just look at the DataRow's RowState property. If it's `Added` the `InsertCommand` will be executed, if it's `Modified` the `UpdateCommand` will be executed. You have to load this row into the table from the database first.

You can fill an empty `DataTable` with a `DataAdapter` and your `SelectCommand` including two parameters. If the table is empty you can add the `DataRow` manually, otherwise you can modify the rows with the updated values (if any) and call `dataAdpater.Update(tempTestTable)`.

Here's an example (untested):

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "SELECT temptesttableid, Age, Name FROM TempTestTable WHERE Name = @Name",
  connection);

DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
// note that you should use an available csv-parser instead
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
{ 
    string[] columns = line.Split(new char[]{'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    if(columns.Length >= 2)
    {
        string name = columns[0].Trim();
        string ageStr = columns[1].Trim();
        int age;
        if (int.TryParse(ageStr, out age))
        {
            dataAdpater.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            int rowsAdded = dataAdpater.Fill(testTable);
            if (rowsAdded == 0)
            {
                testTable.Rows.Add(name, age);
            }
            else
            {
                // update values?
            }
        }
    }
}
dataAdpater.Update(testTable);
```

Comment: Thanks, going to work on implementing this. I guess in the update values part I have to define an UpdateCommand and execute it somehow. Actually I'm not sure how AddWithValue will work without an AddCommand defined...